# react-native: <Picker> loses selectedValue when changing the <Picker.Item> label

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'd like to **change the labels** of the `<Picker.Item>`s of my `<Picker>`, e.g. when the language changes, triggered by another button (`react-redux`).

`key` and `value` should stay the same, just the `label` changes.

Unfortunately the result is a re-rendering(?) and the `selectedValue` changes to the first `<Picker.Item>`s (not to the default!).

```
<Picker 
    selectedValue={this.props.myValue}
    onValueChange={(newValue) => this.props.setMyValue(newValue);}}>

    {this.props.myOptions.map((s, i) => {
        let l = modify(s);
        return <Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={l}/>      
    })}
</Picker>
```

The problem occurs as soon as the `label` changes, e.g. by adding the current date on every change:

```
export default function modify(string) {
    // return string; // works
    return string + '_i_change_' + new Date(); // doesn't work
}
```

I appreciate every advice.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ran into same issue.  You may need to make the selectedValue a string.  eg:

```
selectedValue={this.props.myValue.toString()}
```